# Django, permission error saving on disk, why?

Tags: python, django, nginx

I'm getting a Permissions `Error [Errno 13] Permission Denied` when a workbook on disk using openpyxl:

```
wb.save(path)
```

No file is uploaded. It's a request then the file is generated and delivered (downloaded), and that part works fine. What I'm trying to do is save a copy of that file on disk.

So far I have rw to both group and others. Same error.
Is this a Django or Linux permission issue?

Comment: yup thats linux permission problem, so try running the server using sudo python manage.py runserver and then try to download

Comment: Ok, it went through. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have permissions on `path` directory, check permission on `path`
 directory

Comment: I already set the owner to app_user and given 777. Same result. Any suggestions?